# How do I Use the Drools debugWorkingMemorylistener?

Tags: java, jboss, drools, business-rules, rule-engine

The following line of code straight from the documentation

```
ksession.addEventListener(new DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener());
```

prompts the following error in eclipse

> The method addEventListener(WorkingMemoryEventListener) in the type
>   WorkingMemoryEventManager is not applicable for the   arguments
>   (DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably import `org.drools.event.DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener` instead of `org.drools.event.rule.DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener`.

In our case, the following code works just fine:

```
import org.drools.event.rule.DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener;
import org.drools.event.rule.ObjectInsertedEvent;
import org.drools.event.rule.ObjectRetractedEvent;
import org.drools.event.rule.ObjectUpdatedEvent;
...
StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
ksession.addEventListener(new DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void objectInserted(ObjectInsertedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void objectRetracted(ObjectRetractedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void objectUpdated(ObjectUpdatedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry - my previous question does not show exactly what I was doing ; I removed a cast to statefulknowledgesession that had a call to geteventlisteners then addeventlistener; now using the simpler call as you have and it works - thanks